# IS it possible to open .exe files inside a website that is displayed on the webpage itself instead of just opening it on the computer

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Is it possible to add a load of programs to a website that can be opened within the webpage itself. for example say the animation software blender. Would it be possible to add all the blender files to the website files and execute them within the webpage creating the GUI inside a window sized set of parameters

Comment: Simplest answer: No.

Comment: LOL ...... Are you serious? ... Exe files with command format drive and such things?

Comment: No ... unless the website is showing the view of a remote machine, on which is executing the exe file.

Comment: Never tried but if you can run dukem nukem 3d maybe you may also run something different or more complicated. [js-dos](https://js-dos.com/) or try to make an system image and use some code from [copy.sh v86 project](https://github.com/copy/v86)

Comment: @ChrisCousins Ok I'll bite. Unless  you mean by "view", the output of a camera pointed at the monitor of a remote machine, **how** would you make this happen?

Comment: @gforce301well you may start by looking at streaming; for instance xsplit.

Answer (score 0):

**Updates Based on Inputs:** Amazon recently released a Product/Service named Appstream 2.0 which does exactly what you had asked for, It is a proprietary platform though and has its own learning curve to even set it up. It does work well with solidworks, so it should work with most of other applications too.(*Solidworks are providing the demo of their software via this service as of now(Nov18)*). Also it uses a specific technique which doesn't require a live video stream and instead streams just the changes in images sprites which in itself is pretty interesting.

Another alternative is cameyo which is also a paid service.

As of opensource alternatives, I don't yet know of such a software.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The closest you will ever get to this thing is flash and that too is NOT an exe.

About having a GUI for a software is a different thing, depends upon whether that specific software is exposing an API and maybe a service/Port that its listening to. And maybe making a script based client side `GET` request to that specific service on localhost, maybe.

Anyways, Wanting to run an executable on the client side is totally defeating the purpose of a website. Generally it is the other way round like say, you want to provide a service via website to compress a picture. You can pipe the submitted data to that respective software and then return the result as a response.

Comment: What I mean by this question is say I have blender is it possible to display the window on the website and make the website user able to interact with the window as if the software was installed on their computer, but it is actually all stored on the server side. This would enable say a website where you can login to your account and work on projects online instead of having to do it on your own computer then upload the files after as it would then be all done on the server itself